# Web page tutorial API

Tags: web-app, tutorial

I'm wondering if there is any AP/library that will allow creation of a on-page tutorial for a web application.

The idea is to guide a new user of the web application through first steps in using it.

I know this is very much used in games but not so much in web application.

Any suggestion, link or idea is welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to search for User On-boarding Walk Through tools. In the company I work, we use [Conpass](https://www.conpass.io/en). This blog post has some tips: ["5 of the Best User Onboarding Tools for Walk Throughs"](https://blog.upscope.io/5-user-walk-through-tools-which-make-onboarding-a-breeze-and-double-your-sales/)

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 has a core module built in to help with this call [Tour](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/tour/overview) which is built on the [jQuery Joyride plugin](https://zurb.com/playground/jquery-joyride-feature-tour-plugin).

If the website is built with bootstrap you might try the [bootstraptour plugin](http://bootstraptour.com) git show your users all the features or guide them through some steps.

If your sites is not using a framework which offers a tour api you can build one with Joyride easily enough.

You might also consider a not-so-obvious approach to teaching users your features. StackExchange, and many sites, use a badge system to reward users for doing more things on the site. This coupled with the "Next Reward" system helps to teach users how to use the site and gives them more insight into all the tools the site offers without expecting the user to read endless doc pages and watch boring videos.